# Send the image to another application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to implement the "share" button. It is necessary to send a picture.

That's what I'm doing:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
File outputFile = null;
try {
    outputFile = File.createTempFile("temp_", ".jpg", outputDir);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);

try {
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, 
getResources().getText(R.string.send_via)));
```

but I get a message saying that it's impossible to upload an image. What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

First, third-party apps have no rights to access files in your portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Second, on Android 7.0+, you cannot use `file` `Uri` values, such as those returned by `Uri.fromFile()`.

To solve both problems, use `FileProvider` to make the image available to other apps. Use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` instead of `Uri.fromFile()`, and be sure to add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates using `FileProvider` with third-party apps (for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `ACTION_VIEW`, but the same technique will work for `ACTION_SEND`).